# How to make class addable to fabric via preprocessor defenitions?

Tags: c++

Say we have a base fabric element interface:

```
class BaseFabricElenent {
public:
    BaseFabricElenent(){}
    virtual ~BaseFabricElenent(){}
    virtual void action(){}
};
```

We have an enumeration:

```
enum TypeCode { 
    TypeCodeLive = 10,
    TypeCodeDie = 100
};
```

And we have implementations for our TypeCodes.

We want to get a fabric that would return desired `type` by `TypeCode` as `BaseFabricElenent*` as normal fabric would do.

How to add types to fabric via preprocessor define?

say:

```
class LiveFabricElenent: pulic BaseFabricElenent {
public:
       LiveFabricElenent() :
          BaseFabricElenent(){}
        virtual ~LiveFabricElenent(){}
        virtual void action(){}
};
ADD_TO_FABRIC(LiveFabricElenent);
```

**Update:**

Found this helpfull [article on registration of types into factory on global initialization phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676498/factory-pattern-allocating-memory-at-compile-time-and-how-to-print-compile-time/10677156#10677156) 
. Creating a Define that would generate stub classes for types registring is all that left.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need a macro to achieve your purpose. If you must use the `enum`, do something like this:

```
class Fabric {
public:
  BaseFabricElement* createElement(TypeCode typeCode) {
    switch (typeCode) {
      case TypeCodeLive: return new LiveFabricElement();
      case TypeCodeDead: return new DeadFabricElement();
      // ... other cases ...
      default: return NULL;
    }
  }
};
```

If the creation process does not depend on `Fabric` state, then the `createElement` method can be `static`. I would also consider returning a smart pointer instead of a raw one, and renaming `Fabric` to `Factory`.