# If a class is not used directly from main yet has a static private member could it be left out when compiling and linking with maximal optimization?

Tags: c++, factory

Say we have the factory described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10677156/1056328). Say we have all that example code inside one single project.  As it is said by the author, `DerivedExample`'s static `registrar` constructor shall be executed before main.  Yet that variable is private for that class and is not accessed anywhere in `main` program, also that class is never used directly in `main` body. So I wonder if it could be left out from final executable when compiling/linking with maximal optimization?

If it would be left out, can compilation of that factory and all its elements into shared library garatee that factory elements would not be left out?

Comment: [basic.stc.static]/2 says "If a variable with static storage duration has initialization or a destructor with side effects, it shall not be eliminated even if it appears to be unused, except that a class object or its copy/move may be eliminated as specified in 12.8." That said, there's no notion of *libraries* in the Standard, and *when* this initialization occurs isn't specified for all cases (e.g. when it's in a separate TU, it might be initialized only when any variable of that TU is used).

Comment: @DyP: that could probably the abnwer - there is a "variable with static storage duration" so "it shall not be eliminated even if it appears to be unused".=) (And that is for at least the case of single programm)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600034/is-static-object-guaranteed-to-be-initialized#18600034

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour differs between compilers. Some years ago I implemented such as factory in some code that was compiled on different platforms. It worked fine on the platform where I first wrote it but failed totally on the next one.

If I remember correctly it was GCC that worked and msvc that eliminated the entire class.

So m don't trust compilers and linkers to behave the same. You have to test each one to know.