# Is static object guaranteed to be initialized

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to learn about initialization of static objects.  Static initialization seems pretty straight forward, assuming you understand constant expressions and `constexpr`.  Dynamic initialization seems quite a bit more tricky.

[basic.start.init]/4

> It is implementation-deﬁned whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage duration is done before the ﬁrst statement of main. If the initialization is deferred to some point in time after the ﬁrst statement of main, it shall occur before the ﬁrst odr-use (3.2) of any function or variable deﬁned in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized.

footnote 34

> A non-local variable with static storage duration having initialization with side-eﬀects must be initialized even if it is not odr-used (3.2, 3.7.1).

[basic.start.init]/5

> It is implementation-deﬁned whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static or thread storage duration is done before the ﬁrst statement of the initial function of the thread. If the initialization is deferred to some point in time after the ﬁrst statement of the initial function of the thread, it shall occur before the ﬁrst odr-use (3.2) of any variable with thread storage duration deﬁned in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized.

I assume that "the initial function of the thread" refers to main, and not just threads started with std::thread.

h1.h

```
#ifndef H1_H_
#define H1_H_

extern int count;

#endif
```

tu1.cpp

```
#include "h1.h"

struct S
{
   S()
   {
      ++count;
   }
};

S s;
```

tu2.cpp

```
#include "h1.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   return count;
}
```

tu3.cpp

```
#include "h1.h"

int count;
```

So, if a compiler defers dynamic initialization, it seems that footnote 34 states that `s` must be initialized at some point.  Since there are no other variables with dynamic initialization in the translation unit, there is no other variable to odr-use to force initialization of the variables in tu1.  At what point is `s` guaranteed to have been initialized?

Is main guaranteed to return 1?  Also, is there some way to change this program such that it is no longer guaranteed to return 1?  Alternatively, if it isn't guaranteed, is there some way to change this program such that it becomes guaranteed?

---

I broke the code up so that the definition of `s` is in a different translation unit from `main`.  This avoids the question of whether `main` is odr used.  Given that `s` is the only object in the translation unit, is it guaranteed that `main` will return 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that all this wording is there to describe what will happen in dynamic loaded libraries, but without explicitly naming them.

To summarize how I interpret it: a non-local variable with static storage duration and dynamic initialization will:

1. be initialized before the ﬁrst odr-use of anything in its translation unit;
2. possibly, before starting `main`, but possibly after it.

I interpret the footnote 34 as (but remember that footnotes are not normative):

> When anything in a TU is ord-used, then every non-local variable with static storage duration having initialization with side-eﬀects must be initialized, even the variables that are not odr-used.

So, if there is a TU where nothing is ord-used, then its dynamic initializations may not happen.

## Example

#### h1.h

```
extern int count;
struct S
{
    S();
};
```

#### h1.cpp

```
#include "h1.h"

int count;
S::S()
{
   ++count;
}
```

#### h2.cpp

```
#include "h1.h"
S s;
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include "h1.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", count);
}
```

This could print 0 or 1: since anything in TU h2 is never odr-used, it is unspecified when the code initialization of `s` will be done, if at all.

Naturally, sane compilers will initialize `s` before main, so it will surely print `1`:

```
$ g++ main.cpp h2.cpp h1.cpp -o test1
$ ./test1
1
```

Now, imagine that `h2.cpp` is in a shared library:

```
$ g++ -shared -fPIC h2.cpp -o h2.so
```

And the main file is now:

#### main2.cpp

```
#include "h1.h"
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", count);
    dlopen("./h2.so", RTLD_NOW);
    printf("%d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ g++ -shared -fPIC h2.cpp -o h2.so
$ g++ -rdynamic main.cpp h1.cpp -ldl -o test2
$ ./test2
0
1
```

See? The initialization of `s` has been delayed! The nice part is that it is impossible to reference anything in the dynamic loaded library without first loading it, and loading it will trigger the dynamic initialization. So all is well.

If you think that using `dlopen` is cheating, remember that there are compilers that support delay loading shared libraries (VC++ for example), where the system call to load the library will be generated automatically by the compiler just the first time it is needed.

Comment: I agree that this is likely intended to deal with dynamic libraries.  This sounds like unless you explicitly call something from every translation unit, then it is possible, no matter how unlikely, that a static variable from some translation unit will not be initialized.

Comment: I don't agree with your interpretation of that footnote 34; [basic.stc.static]/2 says "If a variable with static storage duration has initialization or a destructor with side effects, it shall not be eliminated even if it appears to be unused[...]" so it has to be there even if nothing of its TU is odr-used. I don't think it's likely the intent has been to force its existence (even if not odr-used) but not its initialization (if nothing of its TU is odr-used).

Comment: @DyP: [basic.stc.static]/2 forbids the compiler to eliminate an initialized variable even if it is unused. But [basic.start.init]/4 allows to delay its initialization indefinitely if the TU is not odr-used (I think that `elimination` is an optimization term, btw). So if the TU us not odr-used, the variable has to be there, but it may be uninitialized during the whole run of the program. And applying the as-is rule, it is as if the variable does not exist at all!

Answer (score 3):

Without searching for the right pages in the definition I can say that your program is guaranteed to return 1. Every static or global initialization is done before the first command in the main. Global variables are initializes first an then the constructors of global objects are executed. Statics within a function/method scope a initialized before first use. But there is a trap:

```
int count;

struct A
{
   A()
   {
     count=5;
   }
};

struct B
{
   B()
   {
     count=count*2;
   }
};


A a;
B b;

void main(void)
{
  return count;
}
```

As mentioned in a commentary of Ben Voigt, the result is defined if both instances are create in the same translation unit. So in my sample, the result is 10. If the instances are create in different files (and compiled separately to different .obj files) the result is not defined.

Comment: Actually the order is guaranteed between globals in the same compilation unit.  Nothing is specified about ordering across multiple compilation units, however.

Comment: Really? Didn't know that. I had an issue with that in a project, so my readings where the classic "do not do this". Is it legit to change the answer on new information like that?

Comment: 3.6.2 says "Variables with ordered initialization defined within a single translation unit shall be initialized in the order
of their definitions in the translation unit."  and "ordered initialization" includes some template member variables, as well as everything non-template.

Comment: Sure you can update your answer.  Just add more translation units (files).

Comment: Yep. I mistook statics. I shouldn't have look into stackoverflow so late :-( . I corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

"the first odr-use of any function or variable deﬁned in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized" includes the variable to be initialized.

Comment: In the definition `S s;` is `s` odr-used? If not, does it have to be initialized before the value of `count` is copied to the temporary which is to be returned from `main`?

Comment: Yes, but only count is odr-used, and it is statically initialized and in a different translation unit from s.

Comment: @DyP: Initialization of `s` is triggered by odr-use of `main()`.  Initialization of `count` is triggered by its own odr-use (during `S::S()`).

Comment: "Initialization of s is triggered *by odr-use of `main()`*" Hm that would explain it. But where is it specified that `main` is odr-used? The name `main` doesn't appear in an expression in the OP's example, so is there a special rule?

Comment: If `main()` is odr-used, then the question still remains, but with `s` moved to another translation unit.

Comment: @BenVoigt " If the initialization is deferred to some point in time after the ﬁrst statement of the initial function of the thread, it shall occur before the ﬁrst odr-use (3.2) of any variable with thread storage duration deﬁned in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized."  Is `main` a "variable with thread storage duration"?

Comment: @Graznarak: No, it's a function, and use of functions also triggers initialization of statics in the same translation unit, according to your first citation from the Standard (I copied from the wrong citation, sorry)

Comment: [3.2/2] "A non-overloaded function whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression or a member of a set of candidate functions, if selected by overload resolution when referred to from a potentially-evaluated expression, is odr-used, unless it is a pure virtual function and its name is not explicitly qualiﬁed."  I am not sure if this, or some other sentence, covers main.