# Non-local object with thread storage duration

Tags: c++, storage-duration

It is unclear why does object with thread storage duration is not default-initialized? For instance:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
struct S
{
    S(){ cout << "S\n"; }
    ~S(){ cout << "~S\n"; }
};

thread_local S s;

int main()
{
}
```

[IdeOne](http://ideone.com/2eFE0y)

`stdout` is empty. But I expected that `stdout` would contain

```
S
~S
```

It is because sec. 8.5/12 N3797:

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is
>   default-initialized

This does not say anything about storage duration of the object.

Comment: State compiler and version

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit But default-initialization will perform if we remove thread_local specifier.

Comment: If you add a use of `s`, like `s.foo()` in `main`, for some member function `foo`, the expected output appears.

Comment: Hmm there is [basic.stc.thread]/2 "A variable with thread storage duration shall be initialized before its first odr-use [...]" but also [basic.start.init]/5 "If the initialization is deferred to some point in time after the first statement of the intiial function of the thread, it shall occur before the first odr-use of any variable with thread storage duration defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized."

Comment: @dyp It seems I'm beginning to understand. _If a variable with static storage duration has initialization or a destructor with side effects, it shall not be eliminated_. Objects with thread storage duration does not have such restriction. Does this imply that it is implementation defined?

Comment: Possibly. I never really understood how implementers interpret those rules, since the side-effects of the construction of objects with static storage duration might also never appear in some circumstances (I think related to libraries). See http://stackoverflow.com/q/18600034