# Is dynamic loading strictly compatible with the C++ Standard?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, dynamic-loading

Does the use of dynamic loading require any special precautions for code to be strictly legal C++?

The C++11 Standard refers to the order of certain events such as what goes on before the first call to main(). However, dynamic loading seems to pull the rug out from under typical assumptions regarding the ordering of events in a program.

As an example is a quote from §3.6.2.

> Static initialization shall be performed before any dynamic initialization takes place.

In the case of dynamic loading, this seems a nearly impossible obligation if taken literally. A program may incur dynamic initialization and then dynamically load code. If that code contains variables that would normally have been statically initialized, the C++ Standard has been violated. It seems possible that the order of events mandated by the Standard could still appear to be satisfied and be legal by the "as-if" rule but elsewhere on SO others have warned about interpreting that rule too broadly.

Comment: How could a correct program possibly observe the initialization state of variables inside code that hasn't been loaded?

Comment: Exactly, that's why I mention the "as-if" rule. I'm not an expert on all the implications of the "as-if" rule though. Maybe there are other corner cases regarding dynamic loading too.

Comment: There isn't really any wiggle room to interpret the as-if rule more or less broadly, contrary to what might be suggested elsewhere. No observable events happen during static initialization, thus an object may be actually statically initialized at any time before it's used for the first time.

Comment: The statically initialized elements do not EXIST until the dynamic loading has taken place. Thus, from the original program's perspective, it is not statically initialized. Once the dynamic loading starts, the static initialization of that module[1] will happen before dynamic intiialization of the module, and the main program actually using the module won't see the content until it has...

[1 no, the standard doesn't talk about modules, but since there is nothing visible OUTSIDE the module until after it has been loaded, we can in practice see it as an independent executable, more or less].

Comment: Of coruse, you could, in thery write code that uses stuff inside a dynamically loaded module before it has completed, by way of using threads and knowing where the dynamically loaded data will be located, and such - but that's "using data from multiple threads without synchronisation", which certainly is "undefined" in the C++ spec.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18600034

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ standard doesn't have any provision for dynamic modules, so a certain amount of interpretation is necessary.

Yes, static-initialized variables in dynamically loaded modules will be initialized after dynamically initialized variables in the main module. You can observe this, and construct programs where it has an effect on the program's behavior. But if you think of the DLL as a separate program, one which shares the main program's memory space but has its own timeline, you can pretty much apply the same rules at the module level, and use them to predict behavior at the application-wide behavior. The compiler doesn't *want* to surprise you... it just has to sometimes.

Incidentally, initialization order is really the least of your concerns when it comes to the collision between C++ and DLLs. Dynamic modules break far more rules than that, particularly when it comes to RTTI.

Comment: I really like this clever interpretation of "program". I thought the fact that the C++ Standard says a "program" must define a main() function would disprove it but with dynamic loading it's perfectly possible for shared libs to define a dummy main().

Comment: @Praxeolitic Or, to be a really *tricky* language lawyer, it could be said that DLLs are compiled as a freestanding implementation, and hence do not need `main()`.

Comment: @Sneftel: I would regard things like DLLs as one of the major use cases for free-standing implementations, especially on non-Unix environments that allow programs to link to a platform-supplied version of the C library, though some of the features the C and C++ Standards require may not be supportable in all such environments.