# auto init of library(ies) at startup

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a bunch of static `init()` methods, that I need to call at application startup. Sort of like having to do:

```
A::init();
S::init();
//...
```

One way of doing it is to initialize a static variable like this:

```
static bool const b{A::init(), S::init(), false};
```

Do any nicer alternatives exist?

Comment: Do you have similar (symmetric) actions to perform at application shutdown?

Comment: @MatthieuM. No, I destroy everything, that needs to be destroyed in destructors and deleters.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an instance of a startup class that initializes the various components in its constructor and terminates them in its destructor. Example:

```
struct Startup
{
    Startup()
    {
        A::Init();
        B::Init();
    }
    ~Startup()
    {
        B::Term();
        A::Term();
    }
};

namespace { Startup startup; }

int main()
{
    // do stuff being completely oblivious to the startup
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have played with "life before main" a number of times, before realizing that it usually is more painful than necessary.

My advice, therefore:

```
int main() {
    A::init();
    S::init();

    // ...
}
```

For clarity, it might be worth creating an `init` function which will call all those in turn.

And unless the dependency tree between the various libraries is crystal clear, I advise *against* packaging (ie, having `B::init` call `A::init`) because in case of diamond dependencies, you could end up with the base library `init` being called multiple times.

Comment: the diamond thing is true, but a robust `init()` could handle multiple calls just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Don't auto-initialize. Explicitly initialize your sub-systems during startup inside your `main`.

The reasons being:

1. You can control the initialization order
2. If initialization fails, you can handle it properly
3. If initialization causes a crash, you will have an easier time debugging and hopefully have a proper stack trace
4. It ensures you are fully aware of the initialization process

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `init_dispatch` template that calls `init()` through a variadic argument list:

```c++
template<typename T>
struct dispatch
{
    dispatch() { T::init(); }
};

template<typename... Ts>
struct init_dispatch : std::false_type
                     , dispatch<Ts>...
{
    init_dispatch() : dispatch<Ts>{}... {}
};

static bool const b = init_dispatch<A, S>{}.value;
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0409b81c8827ff6b)</kbd>

Comment: @ildjarn I'm not sure I understand the question. What is your concern about the use of `b`?

Comment: If `b` is never ODR-used, why wouldn't the linker optimize it out, and thus the instantiation of `init_dispatch<>`?

Comment: @ildjarn Hmm...that's interesting. Would you know how to prevent something like that should it happen? :)

Comment: I'm not sure of a good answer offhand, but I know there's a wealth of info about it on SO already (which is why I was aware that it was at least potentially an issue). :-] [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18600034/636019) seems particularly pertinent.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would absolutely recommend keeping it simple: initialize stuff within `main`, not with magic statics. That way it's explicit that it happens, and it's explicit *when* it happens. And you can reason about the state of the application before and after it happens.

Anything that happens before and after `main` tend to just lead to trouble down the line.